# Using Angular libraries in Nativescript code sharing project

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to migrate an Angular app to a shared codebase with Nativescript using the new `@nativescript/schematics`, however, I'm having problems importing my Angular library when building the mobile version of the app. I used the angular-cli to create the library (`ng generate library`).

For the web version, all I had to do was build the library separately using `ng build library-name` which then allowed me to import it into the main application.

How can I build a mobile version of the library that can be imported into the main application when running `tns run ios --bundle`? I've already migrated the components and module of the library with appropriate *.tns files.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find any solution?

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: Does this help - https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Nativescript cli do not have this feature where we can build an angular library into npm package and use it in other projects.

I tried a workaround and it worked for me. Write a script to copy all of your project files into another directory and replace all *.tns.ts, *tns.html and *.tns.scss. files with *.ts, *.html and *.scss respectively. Then build these files using regular ng command. You can add a build configuration for the same in angular.json file to build from the copied directory. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is just a hyperlink answer but the space required to answer this, in my opinion, is way too large. I just finished finalizing a [repo](https://github.com/crowmagnumb/ng-shared-example) I've been working on to do exactly this. I have a whole slew of angular web libraries that I now want to make available for use on mobile using NativeScript. I have put everything I have learned so far into this [repo](https://github.com/crowmagnumb/ng-shared-example) and I hope it helps you too.

Thanks for the final push/idea @Rohit, a script for doing what he suggests is in the `test-lib/gulpfile.js` of this repo.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding your linked repository, was it deleted?

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot I had that linked here. I got rid of it because it is out-of-date (Angular 7) and I switched not too long after this to a mono-repo using nx and I won't look back. It has saved me so much time. But I found the code on my laptop so I resurrected the repo. Hope it helps some but I don't know that I could answer any questions about it anymore.

Comment: No problem!  Thank you for putting it back up!