# Angular workspace with multiple Angular + Nativescript Code sharing projects and a resusable library

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular-nativescript

**Environment**

'tns info'
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
‼ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 5.1.0 and the latest available version is 5.1.1.
‼ Update available for component tns-core-modules. Your current version is 5.1.1 and the latest available version is 5.1.2.
√ Component tns-android has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
× Component tns-ios is not installed.

- CLI:  @angular/cli@7.1.4
- Cross-platform modules: N/A
- Android Runtime: latest
- iOS Runtime: N/A
- Plugin(s): N/A
  .

In my workspace I have two nativescript + angular code sharing projects. In my actual projects in a workspace I have an nsconfig.file that points to the files as well as overridden in webpack.config.js for testing as I am not fully sure if the nsconfig is working as expected

When generating a new platform it can never find the Android Manifest in a project, (which is expected) I assume on build It will override these values anyways. However Near the end of running 'tns run android --bundle' it seems to try to direct to a default folder of 'app/' which I cannot see even in a new code sharing project by itself so I am led to believe this is some sort of default path.

Error as as follows:

```
...
[./package.json] 129 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 382 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Could not find folder: C:\Users\userNameHere\Desktop\projects\myProjects\AngularWorkSpace\app
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\userNameHere\Desktop\projects\myProjects\AngularWorkSpace\app\App_Resources\Android'.
```

All project specific files would be in `workspace/projects/applicationOne` not `workspace/app` which I believe is some sort of default path if nothing is found.

**Showing Angular workspace with 2 projects and a feature library:**
[image]

[image]

**To Reproduce**

Create a new empty workspace
Add 2 nativescript Angular code sharing projects
Add a library (possibly not neccessary)
Set up similar structure for reusable platform and webpack.

```
Update nsconfig inside project 1 and 2
{
  "appResourcesPath": "projects/applicationOne/App_Resources",
  "appPath": "projects/applicationOne/src",
  "nsext": ".tns",
  "webext": "",
  "shared": true
}
```

**Expected behavior**

Should be able to have an Angular workspace with multiple applications projects added.
1 `webpack.config.js` for handling building. An `nsconfig.js` per application in the projects folder for paths.
To build per application.

**Additional context**

I believe I have everything set up correctly. I think the only issue is 
`Could not find folder: C:\Users\userNameHere\Desktop\projects\myProjects\AngularWorkSpace**\app**`
The `\app` i think is the default when a path is not specific or found. it should be pointing to `AngularWorkspace/projects/applicationOne`

**Update:**

When I do not override the values for appPath and appResourcesPath in the webpack.config.js file I notce the paths will faile back all of them to workspace/app. This leads me to believe the build is using appPath somewhere else outside of webpack and that I am not overriding it soon enough.

I have read about updating webpack variables such as appPath from the command line, I think the reason is the application is not picking up from the nsconfig from projects/applicationOne and therefor defaults. I think if I can update this value as well as appResourcesPath from the command line then the builds should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Workspace with two Angular + Nativescript Code sharing Project + Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374245/angular-workspace-with-two-angular-nativescript-code-sharing-project-library)